# How to display assets on localhost

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, php, file-permissions

I'm trying to run a site on a MAMP stack, but when I load a page the assets aren't showing up. I inspected the Net tab in Firebug, and my stylesheet tags are pointing to the right CSS files, but the browser is returning a 404 error on each one. I'm almost positive this is a file permissions deal (i.e. user and group). I'm using Mac 10.5, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.3. Is this a PHP or an apache issue? How do I determine what users/groups to change my asset files to?

Comment: What URL are you typing into your browser?

Comment: @JoshCampbell I'm using a CMS, so it's something like 127.0.0.1/modx/index.php?id=5

Comment: Try just typing in localhost and hitting enter. If that doesn't work, try localhost/modex and hit enter. Let me know what it says.

Comment: @JoshCampbell localhost give me an `Index of /` page and localhost/modx displays the home page without styling

Comment: OK, that's what I expected it to do. I build all my websites in notepad, so I am unfamiliar with CMS operations. So far they seem to be the same. You say you checked your style sheet using Firefox and all was good. From the sound of this though, your index page is improperly linked to your CSS and assets. Open up your home page again, right click and select view source. Locate the stylesheet in the <head> section and click on the href="folder/folder/stylesheet.css" portion. If it takes you to the CSS code, then it's linked. If it shows page not found, then it's not linked.

Comment: @JoshCampbell I know the `link href` values are correct b/c I have used the CMS before and have accessed them using the same directory structure. I am pretty sure this is a group/owner problem.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you tried what I suggested and it took you to the CSS code?

Comment: I was just looking at a CMS website and checked the source code behind it. I'm afraid there's so much garbage code behind those things that I probably will do more harm here than good. Sorry.

Comment: @JoshCampbell no, I mean another installation of the CMS on a different OS. That's cool man, thanks anyways.

Comment: I would really prefer that someone familiar with CM systems assist you with your issues. I really don't like giving out bad information. From what you're describing it sounds like your main page or theme, or whatever they're called is not connected to the stylesheet. For all I know the CMS auto-binds these things or some other weird behind the scenes stuff, so I can't instruct you to mess around with it.